# Squaremo amqplib offline messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq, amqp

*NB : I have tried many amqp libraries with nodejs ([RabbitJs](http://www.squaremobius.net/rabbit.js/) and [node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp)) and it seems that we cant use offline messages, so I use [amqplib](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node)*

**Introduction :**

I need to create a mobile backend with realtime socket exchanges, without taking care about network loss.

I've made some search and it seems that using a message broker is a good idea. So I documented myself and tried to implement some things. Here, I m using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

The fact is that I can use the different queue and exchange types, like fanout, direct when I have a full and sure network connection.

I found some informations concerning changing the type of my queue and setting it to "durable:true" and "autoDelete:false" but it doesn't seem to work.

I need the offline message management for working on any kind of queue (1 to 1, 1 to N etc..)

I need to work with [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

**What I've written :**

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');


var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {'pingTimeout': 10000, 'pingInterval': 5000});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(8888);


amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function (conn, err) {
    if (err != null) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        return conn.createChannel().then(function (ch, err) {
            if (err != null) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
                    ch.assertExchange('logs', 'fanout', {durable: false})
                        .then(function () {

                            socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                                ch.publish('logs', '', new Buffer(msg));
                            });

                            return ch.assertQueue('', {durable: true, autoDelete: false});
                        })
                        .then(function (qok) {
                            return ch.bindQueue(qok.queue, 'logs', '').then(function () {
                                return qok.queue;
                            });
                        })
                        .then(function (queue) {
                            return ch.consume(queue, queueConsumed, {noAck: true});
                        });


                    function queueConsumed(msg) {
                        socket.emit('news', msg.content.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Questions**

- How can the library handle offline messaging knowing that the socket can timeout ? Clearly, how can it handle the timeout and heartbeats of socket.IO ?
- In this library, the developper dealt with "channel" that I didn't find in the documentation. What is a channel ? A user connection ?
- What should I change to manage a robust and good offline messaging between my backend, a browser and a smartphone ?

Comment: Have you read https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html ?

Comment: I did, I've read it and I edit my code to be clearer

Comment: So, do you understand now what channels are in AMQP? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#amqp-channels